# How can i add a text behind an image which is png in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

This is a link for what i really want

[https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.photoshopessentials.com%2Fphoto-effects%2Fplace-text-behind-object-photoshop%2F&psig=AOvVaw1hDtDiS8z1fcdcHG0YSX3e&ust=1585469975211000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKCzh4nevOgCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hghR6.jpg)

Guys i want to add a text behind the image(.png) in react native ? There is ImageBackground. I simply need ImageForeground.

```
renderContactsItem = ({ item}) => {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemContainer}
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Modal',{selectedItem:item},)}
    >
      <View style={[styles.card,{backgroundColor:item.color}]}>
        <Image
          style={styles.avatar}
          source={ item.picture }
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View> 
)
```

};

Comment: Can you add an image as an example, for what you need?

Comment: i've added a link which refers an image for what i really need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<View>
  <Text style={{ position: 'absolute', fontSize: 50 }}>
       Your Text to display
  </Text>
  <Image style={{ position: 'absolute' }} source={require('../yourImagePath')} />
</View>
```

You need to style your things around this. I hope this works for you and just style the components according to your requirements in case if you need something more.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ImageBackground` instead of `Image`

```
<View style={styles.container}>
 <ImageBackground source={image} style={styles.image}>
   <Text style={styles.text}>Inside</Text>
 </ImageBackground>
</View>
```

Please go through the official document - [Here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground)

Comment: It is a background image i want to add the text behind the image.